# Cant login to rasberrypi

Tags: boot-issues

I just got my Raspberry pi and I was setting up the timezone and some other things, and when it restarted it wanted a login and password that I do not know. Is there any way to reset it? I did go into boot and click on the first command on accident, Could that be it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are running Raspbian. The username is pi and the password is raspberry.

Comment: ...and if you are not used to *nix operating systems note that no characters will be displayed as you type in the password.